# Pass a text_field custom parameter to a link_to paypal IPN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, parameters, parameter-passing, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to send an email to the client when he successfully makes a transaction using paypal.

I've already manage to send the custom `email` parameter to paypal in a [custom](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) parameter they provide.

**What I have right now**

My `product` model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    # This defines the paypal url for a given product sale
        def paypal_url(return_url, cancel_return, useremail) 
        values = { 
        :business => 'your_business_email@example.com',
           :cmd => '_xclick',
        :upload => 1,
        :return => return_url,
        :rm => 2,
        :cancel_return => cancel_return,
        :custom => useremail
        }   
        values.merge!({ 
        "amount" => unit_price,
        "item_name" => name,
        "item_number" => id,
        "quantity" => '1'
        })
             # For test transactions use this URL
    "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
    end

    has_many :payment_notifications


end
```

here, I'm passing a parameter for the `:custom` object which I have it **hardcoded** in the button `link_to` helper here:

```
<%= link_to 'checkout', @product.paypal_url(payment_notification_index_url, root_url, 'testing@testing.com') %>
```

This works perfectly, and I am able to store the `custom` email in the database:

```
class PaymentNotificationController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery except: [:create]

  def create
    # @payment = PaymentNotification.create!(params: params, product_id: params[:invoice], status: params[:payment_status], transaction_id: params[:txn_id] )
    @payment = PaymentNotification.create!(params: params, product_id: 1, status: params[:payment_status], transaction_id: params[:txn_id], email: params[:custom] )
    # render nothing: true

    if @payment.status == 'Completed'
      PaymentTransactions.success(@payment).deliver_now
      redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Success!'
    else
      redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Error'
    end

  end
end
```

[image]

**Question**

How do I get the client to input their email in a field and pass that value into the parameters of the `link_to` so that paypal return the email so I can store it in the database and send an email to the client?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use link_to, but form_tag with method: :get

```
<%= form_tag (@product.paypal_url(payment_notification_index_url, root_url, :custom)),method: :post do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :custom %>
  <%= submit_tag 'checkout' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: was able to just add the third parameter as `:custom` and `method: :post` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

This might be ***more*** than what you're expecting...but read on.

Before you dive further into the implementation, keep in mind that, you're using the `sandbox` version of Paypal for **testing**, and in **production**, you'd want the `paypal_url` to return an **encrypted url** for the `user` as to avoid *tampering* of the transaction, such as changing the price (more details at [Railscast #143](http://www.railscasts.com/episodes/143-paypal-security)).

Now, realize that any approaches on the client-side via javascript to get the user email field and modify the link will not be *secure* as **the link should be generated from your server after encryption** (and you'd need to pass in the user email as part of the call).

So, what can you do? Use **ajax** to send the request to the server containing the parameters (e.g. return_url, user_email, etc..), and respond in the server with an **encrypted link**. Then, you can use javascript to replace the link and allow user to click that instead.

As you realize, the implementation above is very general and any answer would not suit your specific case. You should keep the above in mind as you'd be required to do that anyway down the road.

Comment: makes sense, I got the link to get the third parameter (the client email) doing what @nicolasmaloeuvre said. I'll be taking a look on how to encrypt the `paypal_url`. Thanks for the info! Also, is the `paypal_url` the same but without the `sandbox` word for live/production?

Comment: @Johhan Yes, simply remove `sandbox` for production, the encrypted `paypal_url` looks something like this `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&encrypted=-----BEGIN+PKCS7----------END+PKCS7-----`

Comment: can you point me out to a tutorial on how to to encrypt the url?

Comment: @Johhan Check out Railscast #143 by Ryan Bates (http://railscasts.com/episodes/143-paypal-security)

Comment: awesome, was able to do the encryption, now let see how it goes when I test it live. Thank you so much

Comment: Hey there, if it's not much to ask, would you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058125/delivery-status-failed-notify-url-ipn-in-ruby-on-rails