# Delivery status Failed notify_url IPN in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-ipn

I get the following error:

```
2015-08-17T18:46:59.095260+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/payment_notification" status=500
```

this is my model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
def paypal_encrypted(return_url, notify_url, cancel_return, useremail) 
        values = { 
        :business => 'facilitatoremail@example.com',
           :cmd => '_xclick',
        :upload => 1,
        :return => return_url,
        :rm => 1,
        :notify_url => notify_url,
        :cancel_return => cancel_return,
        :custom => useremail,
        :cert_id => 'myid'
        }   
        values.merge!({ 
        "amount" => unit_price,
        "item_name" => name,
        "item_number" => id,
        "quantity" => '1'
        })

        encrypt_for_paypal(values)
    end



    has_many :payment_notifications
end

PAYPAL_CERT_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/certs/paypal_cert.pem")
APP_CERT_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/certs/app_cert.pem")
APP_KEY_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/certs/app_key.pem")

def encrypt_for_paypal(values)
  signed = OpenSSL::PKCS7::sign(OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(APP_CERT_PEM), OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(APP_KEY_PEM, ''), values.map { |k, v| "#{k}=#{v}" }.join("\n"), [], OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)
  OpenSSL::PKCS7::encrypt([OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(PAYPAL_CERT_PEM)], signed.to_der, OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher::new("DES3"), OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY).to_s.gsub("\n", "")
end
```

My controller for the post is:

```
class PaymentNotificationController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery :except => [:create]

  def create
    @payment = PaymentNotification.create!(params: params, product_id: 1, status: params[:payment_status], transaction_id: params[:txn_id], email: params[:custom] )
    render nothing: true

    if @payment.status == 'Completed'
      PaymentTransactions.success(@payment).deliver_now
    end

  end
end
```

My button:

```
<%= form_tag "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :cmd, "_s-xclick" %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :encrypted, @product.paypal_encrypted(root_url, payment_notification_index_url, root_url, :custom) %>
  <%= text_field_tag :custom %>
  <%= submit_tag 'checkout encrypted' %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Paypal sends the POST but I get the error STATUS=500

All the payment proceed normally but I just want that paypal do a POST using `notify_url`.

I'm testing this in `Heroku` since testing locally will not work.

Also, if I use the `return_url` to make the post instead, it will work and return STATUS=200.

But I don't want to use this since the gap between the user doing the transaction and being redirected back to the `return_url`.

**EDIT**

after integrating `Airbrake` this is what I got in return

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I changed the data encoding for data sent from PayPal to UTF-8

[image]

When I tried again, the status was still 500 but I got the transaction saved in the database BUT paypal kept getting a failed attempt and kept retrying so instead of one record being saved I had multiple records

The error I'm getting now is this one:

[image]

Right now at least the transactions are saved but paypal seems to fail to recognized that.

**SOLVED**

Apparently, it was my mailer that wasn't configured in production.. I was just able to comment that part and push in heroku and tried again. It successfully went trough with a STATUS=200 and the error was solved in `Airbrake`.

Thank you all!

Comment: Can you add the full error stacktrace? The status 500 is an error response from your app in Heroku, but we need to see error details, line code, etc.

Comment: `2015-08-17T19:18:20.769878+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/payment_notification" host=example.herokuapp.com request_id=503dc673-6ed5-43ba-b031-56c397a4ee5d fwd="173.0.82.126" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=558ms status=500 bytes=139429`

Comment: @Johhan Have you tried making a `POST` request manually by using `curl` to see your routing is correct?

Comment: I tried it locally and it did work and saved the record in the database. Would `curl` work if I make a post to the heroku server?

Comment: We still need a little more information about the error. Try adding a error notification service like Rollbar or Airbrake if you can't get that information with a simple rescue / log. That way you can inspect the params esnt by Paypal, and reproduce that with `curl` locally. Also, routing is correct (not 404 but 500). You have an error somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set your system encoding in PayPal account? It's somewhere under 'PayPal button encoding' in your profile, and you should set 'Send the data to me in the same encoding' to UTF-8.

As was discovered in comments, another error was due to misconfigured mailer. Note that #render call doesn't send data to client immediately, it just queues it until action ends.

Comment: I edited the question adding the process you told me to do, I got one problem solved but that created another one.

Comment: Please fetch and provide full error log. Although from the looks of it, you've got problem with your mailer. Check mailer settings in `production.rb`.

Comment: should I comment that out and see if that fix it?

Comment: ok so that was the problem... I haven't configured the email in production yet wow.. how did you notice?

Comment: So I see, the smtp error logs were all over the place and literally in my face... thank you!

Comment: The UTF-8 issue caused errors and PayPal mailed me their 'PayPal Instant Payment Notification Warning' threatening to stop my IPN if it won't be fixed. Hopefully fixing their unorthodox encoding will stop getting threats from them :)

Comment: Specifying UTF-8 through the profile settings doesn't seem to be enough , the fix here seems to be more robust. params.each { |k, v| params[k] = v.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8') }
https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/4nw7xn/help_force_utf8_encoding_on/

Comment: @OhadDahan You should create another answer for that question — so that if anyone finds that your solution if more up-to-date it will bubble up.