# PayPal IPN : Completed 500 Internal Server JSON::GeneratorError (source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, paypal, paypal-ipn

I was receiving the following error when I tried to save the parameters from PayPal IPN notification:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server JSON::GeneratorError (source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8):
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar questions at:
[Delivery status Failed notify_url IPN in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058125/delivery-status-failed-notify-url-ipn-in-ruby-on-rails)
https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/4nw7xn/help_force_utf8_encoding_on/

The latter one had the correct answer:

```
params.each { |k, v| params[k] = v.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8') }
```

PayPal were sending non UTF-8 characters , causing the error and PayPal threatening to stop my IPN due to too many failed messages.